# Sniff local network iOS game host

Tags: ios, adhoc, sniffing

I am having a little issue right here.
I want to sniff an iOS game that makes an ad-hoc connection to another iOS device using the local network to get multiplayer, but I am unable to sniff these packets, I've tried with Wireshark but no luck (I think I am doing it wrong). 
What can I do to intercept the connection between these two devices?

Answer (score 0):

If it's on a WPA network, I think you need to do the sniffing on the AP. Alternatively, put all three devices on an ad-hoc WEP network.

There's also peer-to-peer bluetooth. I'd avoid that by turning it off, instead of trying to sniff a bluetooth key exchange.